# Github actions rails commands "/bin/ruby: invalid option -: (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, github, github-actions

Im trying to implement Github Actions but not able to run the rails commands.

Raises errors when running `bundle exec rake` or `bundle exec rails db:create` in the github workflow.

```
Run bundle exec rake rails db:setup
  bundle exec rake rails db:setup
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    PATH: /home/runner/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/usr/share/rust/.cargo/bin:/home/runner/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/home/runner/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin
    RAILS_ENV: test
    POSTGRES_HOST: localhost
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    RUBYOPT: -W:no-deprecated -W:no-experimental
/home/runner/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby: invalid option -:  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

and here is my ruby.yml file:

```
name: Ruby

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  test:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:11
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Ruby
      uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: 2.6.5
    - name: Install library for postgres
      run: sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: bundle install
    - name: Setup Database
      run: bundle exec rake rails db:setup
      env:
        RAILS_ENV: test
        POSTGRES_HOST: localhost
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
        RUBYOPT: "-W:no-deprecated -W:no-experimental"
    - name: Run tests
      env:
        RAILS_ENV: test
        POSTGRES_HOST: localhost
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
        RUBYOPT: "-W:no-deprecated -W:no-experimental"
      run: bundle exec rake
    - name: Ensure that assets compile correctly
      run: bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

Thank you everyone!

Comment: try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma  I tryied using it instead of localhost and its raising the same error. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

`RUBYOPT='-W:no-deprecated` is not available for Ruby versions <2.7.

Change

```
ruby-version: 2.6.5
```

to

```
ruby-version: 2.7.0
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, i will try it now. Hope the new version doesn't break any other code LOL. Thank you

Comment: Thanks! Had this set in my `.bashrc` (probably to suppress some previous deprecation warnings while some post-2.7 ruby version was in use), commenting it out got ruby working again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could give you any help. But, you can try to do what I did based on my finding.

Go to the root directory of your app. Run the `pwd` command and see if there's any space in the path. And based on your problem, it probably have a space prior to `:` char.

I renamed my folder name which containing the space, and everything works fine

I hope it can help